# [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function when using fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

I'm getting the error

> 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]:

Callback must be a function
    at `maybeCallback (fs.js:129:9)`
    at `Object.writeFile (fs.js:1159:14)`'
But i'm not totally sure why. I have a function that should write JSON data to a file and from all the information i've seen online this should work?

```
  fs.writeFile('config/stuff.json', JSON.stringify(stuff))
```

where stuff is just an array of items e.g. `['1', '2', '3']`

Comment: You need to provide a callback function as the third argument. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Answer (score 2):

`fs.writeFile` has two overloaded methods 1st one takes four argument 2nd one takes 3 arguments. and in both of them last argument must be a callback function which is called after file has been written or an error has occurred. See documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)